# Update git-svn list of remote branches

Tags: git, svn, branch, git-svn

When I have to use svn, I use git-svn to talk to svn. I cloned the repo with the standard git svn clone -s line, and all the remote branches at the time were there.

Since then, a new branch has been created, but not by me. I want to checkout/track this branch locally. I can track a branch that I can see (with git branch -r) like so:

```
git checkout -t -b dev remotes/development
```

But this doesn't work with the other branch, since it doesn't show up in git branch -r

How can I track this missing branch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell git-svn about a remote branch created after I fetched the repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296975/how-do-i-tell-git-svn-about-a-remote-branch-created-after-i-fetched-the-repo)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

After running the following commands, you'll be able to see the new branch on the git side:

```
$ git svn fetch
$ git svn rebase
```

Make sure your branch is clean first.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I normally just ``git svn rebase``.  Adding fetch does the trick.

Answer (score 10):

```
git svn rebase
```

will rebase the current branch and all the branches that you have indicated should be automatically fetched in your local repository configuration.

```
git svn fetch
```

will fetch all the branches from the SVN repository as described when you originally did the git svn clone (including new ones). This is in contrast to the behaviour of

```
git fetch
```

which only fetches the branches you've specified, as with the *git svn rebase*.

This difference is primarily because git can't "see" the SVN remotes branches until they've been pulled into the local repository vs when you clone a git repository and *git branch -a* shows all the remote branches (even those that aren't tracked/won't be updated with a fetch).

Answer (score -2):

`git svn rebase --fetch-all` will tackle it, refer to the [man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn):

> This fetches revisions from the SVN
> parent of the current HEAD and rebases
> the current (uncommitted to SVN) work
> against it.
>
> [...]
>
> This works similarly to svn update or git pull
>
> [...]
>
> This accepts all options that git svn fetch and git rebase accept. However, --fetch-all only fetches from the current [svn-remote], and not all [svn-remote] definitions.

:i: BUT it fetches all svn copies / branches

Comment: You need to do a git svn fetch and then a git svn rebase.

Comment: @Chesney not a feature but a bug?

Comment: oh, you're right, it does imply the fetch, but not - regarding the question - fetching the branches as I tested myself https://gist.github.com/childnode/979812d69a3f266baede you need to add `--fetch-all` option. answer edited