# Is it possible to add a branch to a git svn repository that was cloned from the Subversion repository's trunk?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have a git-svn repository I had originally cloned from an svn repo's trunk, like so:

```
http://server/svn/MxProject/trunk
```

Since I cloned only the trunk and didn't grab the branches directory, is there a way I can access the branch without doing a full clone?

Comment: Instead of just cloning the trunk you should be cloning SVN repositories with the -s argument.  This will give you a folder with the same structure as just the trunk but enable you to use branches and tagging.  Read more in the docs about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, I found the solution AFTER I posted the question lol. Hope this helps point someone else in the right direction:

[I found the solution on this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296975/how-do-i-tell-git-svn-about-a-remote-branch-created-after-i-fetched-the-repo).