# Files of new SVN branch are fetched with wrong path when running git svn fetch

Tags: git, branch, git-svn, fetch

I have a git repository cloned from SVN with std layout a while ago. (It was done with git svn init and git svn fetch). Now I am using git 1.7.9.
My svn-remote config section looks like this:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = https://myhost/svn/myProject
        fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
        branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
        tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

All branches that were initially fetched work correctly, subsequent fetches are also correct on these branches and on trunk.
The directory structure looks like this under each branch:

```
subProject1\src\myPackage
subProject2\src\
subProject3\src\
```

Now a new branch called 2_7_1 was created with matching the directory structure of all other branches and the trunk.

Now when I run *git svn fetch* it starts fetching each revision from r1 instead of only fetching it from the revision where 2_7_1 branch was created from trunk.
The reason seems to be that it assumes: *src\myPackage* directory structure instead of *subProject1\src\myPackage*, so it starts fetching all revisions starting from r1.

When I browse the SVN repo in a browser I see no difference in the directory structure.
I noticed only one difference that the new branch is called 2_7_1@18813 (18813 is the start revision number of the new branch) where all other branches do not contain the revision, only the branch name.

I do not want to do a use the solution provided here: [How do I tell git-svn about a remote branch created after I fetched the repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296975/how-do-i-tell-git-svn-about-a-remote-branch-created-after-i-fetched-the-repo) , because it would lose the common parent for trunk and 2_7_1 branch.

***Edit:***
After doing a full *git svn fetch* it has become clear for me that my git svn sees two branches: 2_7_1 and 2_7_1@18813. 2_7_1@18813 was fetched from revision #1. And this messed up my master branch earlier tracking the SVN trunk.

Now my branch structure looks like this (a complete mess):

```
------------------------------------------- X -- Y -- Z  ==  masterNew/trunk

-- A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G ----  == 2_7_1@18813
                                    \  \
                                     \  \ - J - K - L == master (old trunk)
                                      \
- A' - B' - C' - D' - E' - F' - G' -- H -- I == 2_7_1
```

***Edit #2:***
After doing a full clone of the SVN repo with git svn clone the problem still persist.

Answer (score 0):

You could branch from the common parent into the 2_7_1 branch, then rig that branch to git-svn with the instructions from [How do I tell git-svn about a remote branch created after I fetched the repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296975/how-do-i-tell-git-svn-about-a-remote-branch-created-after-i-fetched-the-repo)

Comment: In SVN 2_7_1 was branched from trunk revision number #18813, so the common parent of trunk and 2_7_1 in SVN is r18813.