# git svn branch history missing

Tags: git, git-svn

I am using "git svn" to clone a SVN repo. The SVN repo I am working with does not follow the standard convention for SVN branch (puts branch in say folder called "bugs", rather than "branch"). Developers like me are suppose to work on branches created in this bug folder.

To be able to develop against these bug plus to be able to test if it merges fine, Here is what I do.

1. I clone the svn trunk as master branch.
2. I then checked out a branch that tracks the SVN branch (svn/bugs).

   I followed the instruction in this link to create a git branch on my local.

[How do I tell git-svn about a remote branch created after I fetched the repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296975/how-do-i-tell-git-svn-about-a-remote-branch-created-after-i-fetched-the-repo)

On master (svn trunk), when I do "git log", see the entire svn history. Which I want.
But, in my bug branch, when I do "git log", it only shows the last commit that was done for creating the branch.  If I import the same svn branch directly (not using git), I do see all the other commit history.

Can anyone tell me How I can link the history on this "git svn branch" (bug branch) so I get the entire history? (i want be able to do git blame to find all the changes)

Comment: Is the problem here that you're missing commits from the branch, or that the branch isn't shown as a branch from the Subversion trunk?

Comment: @me_and, I just updated the question to clarify my issue.

Comment: When you say "I then clone branch", do you mean you run `git svn clone`? I'm also not clear what you mean by "it only shows the last commit that was done for creating the branch" – do you mean you only see the most recent Subversion commit for that branch, or you only see the Subversion commit that initially created the branch?

Comment: I checked out the branch as indicated in the link above. Next, when I run "git log" on that new branch, I only see 1 commit. and that is the commit that was done for creating the branch in SVN. I do not see any older history.

Comment: Did you ever resolve your issue? I am experiencing a similar problem.