# Adding another directory for branches in git-svn

Tags: git, git-svn

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296975/how-do-i-tell-git-svn-about-a-remote-branch-created-after-i-fetched-the-repo), you can edit your `.gitconfig` and tell git-svn where to go about to push your latest code change.

In my case, I have a special case where nor the Tags and nor the Branches can be used. So, if you look at the SVN repo, you see something like this:

```
trunk
branches
tags
xtra
```

I am new to git-svn and up to know I was fine with working directly with the trunk. Things changed and I need to work with xtra folder and create subfolders in there e.g. `xtra/Job1234/`  and push into it. How can I do such change ?

If I type `git svn info`, I get:

```
URL: https://some.net/repositories/myproject/base/trunk
```

Clearly, any `git svn dcommit` pushes things to the trunk. Any leads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ git config --add svn-remote.svn.branches "xtra/*:refs/remotes/xtra/*"       ①
$ git svn branch -d xtra Job1234                                              ②
$ git checkout --track remotes/xtra/Job1234                                   ③
```

... and you should be ready to commit!

---

<sup>Yes, you can also do the equivalent of ① by directly editing `.git/config`.</sup>

Comment: Progress but not there yet.

Comment: When I type: $git svn branch -d base/xtra Job1234  ...I get an error saying that the destination does not exist... When you look at it you wind up with the destination looking like: https://<somepath>.net/repo/base/base/xtra/Job1234... For some reason base is there twice

Comment: @user643605, that means that my guess about your Subversion repo root was wrong. (You should've specified it in your question). See edit.

Comment: So I changed the first command line from "base/xtra/*:refs/remotes/xtra/* to "/xtra/*:refs/remotes/xtra/*" ... Then I type the second command line and I get an error: " ...searching aggressively for old history"... For some reason something is not found and it starts iterating to fix it.

Comment: "searching aggressively for old history" is not an error. Read carefully that line from begginning to end, and the previous one. `git-svn` is working as expected, you can verify that with `git branch -av` when it completes.

Comment: this is what I did and it worked for me.  1) Added a line in .git/config under [svn-remote "svn"] branches = xtra/my_repo/*:refs/remotes/my_repo/*   2) git svn branch -d xtra/my_repo Job1234   3) git checkout --track refs/remotes/my_repo/Job1234... thanks to ulidtko!

Answer (score 0):

Note that `git svn branch` can segfault before Git 2.17 (Q2 2018) will provide a workaround for segfault with more recent versions of SVN.

See [commit 7f6f75e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f6f75e97acd25f8e95ce431e16d2e1c2093845d) (29 Jan 2018) by [Eric Wong (`ele828`)](https://github.com/ele828).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9cd5320](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9cd5320d3cfb2c2841a76b36b20c18e9299206ab), 13 Feb 2018)</sup>

> ### `git-svn`: control destruction order to avoid segfault
>
> It seems necessary to control destruction ordering to avoid a segfault with SVN 1.9.5 when using "git svn branch".
>   I've also reported the problem against `libsvn-perl` to [Debian Bug #888791](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=888791),
>   but releasing the `SVN::Client` instance can be beneficial anyways to
>   save memory.