# git-svn local branch tracking remote svn branch

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I checkout my own private branch on svn like this:

```
git svn clone svn://server/cfe/project/branches/fb_oz_3173_email
```

Now I am on the branch `master`.

I would like to:

- rename this branch to `fb`
- add branch called master which tracks the remote `svn://server/cfe/project/trunk`

I can't get it right. Can someone give me a lead?

### update

- the first part is easy: 
  `git branch -m fb`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the second part has also an answer

```
git config --add svn-remote.newbranch.url https://svn/path_to_newbranch/
git config --add svn-remote.newbranch.fetch :refs/remotes/newbranch
git svn fetch newbranch [-r<rev>]
git checkout -b local-newbranch -t newbranch
git svn rebase newbranch
```

Originally posted here [How do I tell git-svn about a remote branch created after I fetched the repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296975/how-do-i-tell-git-svn-about-a-remote-branch-created-after-i-fetched-the-repo)