# git - restore deleted svn branch without rereading svn history

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I've accidentaly removed svn branch from my local git repo. Branch is still on the server, and I still have git branch which was tracking this svn branch.

I'd like to restore this branch where it was. If I do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296975/how-do-i-tell-git-svn-about-a-remote-branch-created-after-i-fetched-the-repo) 
git starts fetching this branch as a new, independent branch with no common ancestor and duplicated history entries. That's what I was afraid of.

Is there any way I could tell git to create svn branch at given commit-ish so it's history will be integrated with what I already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I handled this situation by myself:

1. At .git\svn\refs\remotes\svn\ there was a 'copy' of deleted branch with @ in name. Something like this: .git\svn\refs\remotes\svn\branch@248166. I made a copy of this directory with @248166 removed.
2. I've created file .git\refs\remotes\svn\branch with commit-ish taken from my tracking branch.
3. I've launched `git svn fetch -r 633500:HEAD` where 633500 is svn revision for one svn commit before.

And it worked.